# EXC_BAD_ACCESS after memory warning

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, uiimage, didreceivememorywarning

I'm having a problem in my application with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS after receiving a memory warning.
This is how I'm testing:
I wrote a simple application that just allocates memory but doesn't free it. After I allocated a lot of memory leaving only about 14 MB free memory, I switch to my main application. Immediately I receive a memory warning in didReceiveMemoryWarning. Moments later my app crashes in a function that sets an image in an UIButton:

```
-(void)activateRecordButton
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audioRecordOn"];
    [recButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

The error I get is EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=some_address) on the line which calls setImage.
If I comment these lines, my app crashes in an another function that sets an image for a UIButton.

This is my didReceiveMemoryWarning:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}
```

Why is this happening? Is this because there is no more memory to load the images or because recButton was deallocated somehow, when the other app allocated a lot of memory?

I'm running on an Iphone 4 ios 5.1.1

Comment: Yes, probably recButton is deallocated. Are you using ARC?

Comment: No, I'm not using ARC. So what should I do in such cases? Recreate the view from scratch?

Comment: How are you creating the button? Is it an IBOutlet?

Comment: All the views should be released in viewDidUnload method and recreated in the viewDidLoad

Comment: hi you are not giving image extension.......

Comment: The button is custom created. `recButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"audioRecord"];
 
    [recButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [recButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"audioRecordOnPush"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    
 [recButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100.0,406.0,120,44)];
 [recButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopRecordButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:recButton];`

Comment: @Rajneesh071 According to `imageNamed` documentation, "On iOS 4 and later, if the file is in PNG format, it is not necessary to specify the .PNG filename extension. Prior to iOS 4, you must specify the filename extension." And even if imageNamed returned `nil`, this wouldn't cause the crash.

Comment: @Diurpaneus is this button creation happening in `viewDidLoad`? Because the button is created with `buttonWithType` (a `retainCount` of zero), when you add it to the view it is retained, but when the view is removed, the button will released. So, if you're not doing this button creation in `viewDidLoad`, then the button would have been released on you, but never recreated when the view reloads.

Comment: This was not happening in viewDidLoad. The problem was that I wasn't retaining the button. I fixed it now,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A UIViewController will by default release its view in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` (if possible). Your button will also be released if you didn't retain it manually.

`setImage` is then called on a nonexistent object and this will trigger a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Comment: You're right.

In 'viewDidUnload' you must set 'nil' to all your views (buttons, labels, ...)/

Comment: More importantly, he has to recreate the button in `viewDidLoad`.